# static class variable reset on mac typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, websocket, static

I have web sockets in my project. when connecting a client, I generate an id for uniqueness and save it in a static class variable, but when I use the getClient method, it returns an empty array. This is exactly what happens on the Mac. I tested it on two different macs. But in Windows it works fine. Didn't check in Linux. my code:

```
export class WSServer {
  private static _wsClients: WSClients[] = [];
  private static _messageSubscribe = new Subject<WebsocketMessage>();

  static messageSubscribe(
    callback: (value: WebsocketMessage) => void
  ): Subscription {
    return this._messageSubscribe.subscribe({
      next: callback,
      error: (e) => {
        console.log(e);
      },
    });
  }

  static getClient(id: string | number) {
    return this._wsClients.find((client) => {
      if (client.id === id) {
        return client;
      }
    });
  }

  static init(server: Websocket.Server<Websocket.WebSocket>): void {
    server.addListener("connection", async (client, request) => {
      const routeDetails = routeSort(request.url);

      if (!routeDetails.valid) {
        client.close();
        return;
      }
      const secureResult = socketSecurity(routeDetails.param);
      if (!secureResult.valid) {
        client.close();
        return;
      }
      let session: Sessions | null;
      if (secureResult.hasSession) {
        session = await Sessions.findOne({
          where: { sessionId: secureResult.data?.session_id },
        });
        if (!session) {
          client.close();
          return;
        }
        await session.update({ online: true, last_sign: new Date().getTime() });
      } else {
        session = await Sessions.create({
          platform: secureResult.data?.session!.platform!,
          brand: secureResult.data!.session!.brand!,
          web: secureResult.data!.session!.web!,
          mobile: secureResult.data!.session!.mobile!,
          last_sign: new Date().getTime(),
          online: true,
        });
      }
      this._wsClients.push({
        id: session.socket_id,
        ws: client,
        session_id: session.sessionId,
      });
      const options = new LocalOptions();
      client.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "connection",
          data: {
            session_id: session.sessionId,
            socket_id: session.socket_id,
            prod_mode: options.prodMode,
          },
        })
      );
      client.on("close", () => {
        this._wsClients = this._wsClients.filter((val) => {
          return val.id != session?.socket_id;
        });
        session?.update({ online: false, last_sign: new Date().getTime() });
      });
      client.on("error", () => {
        this._wsClients = this._wsClients.filter((val) => {
          return val.id != session?.socket_id;
        });
        session?.update({ online: false, last_sign: new Date().getTime() });
      });
      client.on("message", (value) => {
        try {
          this._messageSubscribe.next(JSON.parse(value.toString()));
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      });
      console.log("client connected!");
    });
    LocalOptions.subscribe("prodMode", (val) => {
      for (const c of this._wsClients) {
        const data: any = {
          type: "changedProdMode",
          data: {
            prod: val,
          },
        };
        c.ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    });
  }

  static send<T = WebsocketMessage>(clientId: number | string, message: T) {
    const client = this._wsClients.find((item) => {
      return item.id == clientId;
    });
    if (client) {
      client.ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to create a variable outside the class and record the clients there but the result is the same. Launched and tested in windows everything works fine but the same code and the same libraries but does not work on macOS. I tried on a poppy with an intel processor and with an apple processor. The result is the same.